# Moving scripts from GAS to office-js

Tags: google-apps-script, office-js, office-addins, porting, office-scripts

I have written some scripts for spreadsheets in Google Apps Script. Right now, I have to move them to Excel. The scripts are not really difficult, they just fill a table with content from another table of the same spreadsheet. It's a shift plan for a full year.

What is the easiest way to get the scripts work in Excel (Web)?

I have the impression the best way is to put them in office.js. So far I have only access to Script Lab but I think that should work, too. But which things do I have to adapt in the coding?

Hear a sample script written in GAS. Unfortunately the variables are german words.
And remember: I'm not a programmer! But it worked. ;-)

```js
function regKuerzelEintragen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Skripte");
  var variablen = sheet.getRange("B28:B41").getValues(); // Get variables for Script (i.e. Range of shift plan, Name of Spreadsheet with shif plan...)
  var sheetJP = ss.getSheetByName(variablen[0][0]); // Spreadsheet with shift plan

  var mitarbeiter = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue(); // Name of employee
  var eintraege = sheet.getRange("C6:G6").getValues(); // Type of shift (as an array of 5 days)
  eintraege[0][5] = ""; // +2 days (Sa/So) --> full week
  eintraege[0][6] = "";
  var nichtUeberschreiben = ["MS", "BV", "EU", "UB", "UG", "FB", "ABW", "ÜF", "DF", "TD", "T1", "T2", "ND", "UC", "RD", "HC", "LH", "NC", "AG", "LA"]; // do not overwride these Types


  // Range of shift plan

  var linksoben = variablen[1][0];
  var rechtsunten = variablen[2][0];
  var datumsZeile = variablen[3][0];
  var mitarbeiterspalte = variablen[4][0];

  var startDatum = new Date(sheet.getRange("C7").getValue()); // enter shift from this date on.
  var startDatumLesbar = startDatum.getDate() + "." + (startDatum.getMonth() + 1) + "." + startDatum.getFullYear();

  var Schichtplan = sheetJP.getRange(linksoben + ":" + rechtsunten).getValues(); // total ARRAY of shift plan
  var nichtAT = Schichtplan.length - 1;

  var mitarbeiterGefunden = false;
  var startDatumGefunden = false;
  var counter = 0;


  // Prompt user before start

  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
    "⚠️ Daten in den Jahresplan einfügen?",
    "Es sollen für: " + mitarbeiter +
    "\n ab dem: " + startDatumLesbar +
    "\n wöchentlich folgende Kürzel eingetragen werden: " + eintraege,
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) { // start search

    for (var zeile in Schichtplan) { // search for employee
      if (Schichtplan[zeile][0] == mitarbeiter) {
        if (!mitarbeiterGefunden) {
          mitarbeiterGefunden = true;

          for (var spalte in Schichtplan[0]) { // search for starting date
            if (Schichtplan[0][spalte] >= startDatum) {

              startDatumGefunden = true;
              var wochentag = Schichtplan[0][spalte].getDay() - 1; // get weekday (set 0=monday)

              if ((eintraege[0][wochentag] != "") && (Schichtplan[nichtAT][spalte] == "")) {
              
                if ((Schichtplan[zeile][spalte] == "") || !(nichtUeberschreiben.includes(Schichtplan[zeile][spalte].toString().toUpperCase()))) {
                  Schichtplan[zeile][spalte] = eintraege[0][wochentag]; // edit shift plan on weekday
                  counter++;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          if (counter > 0) {

            // WRITE ARRAY IN SPREADSHEET

            // correct range of array
            Schichtplan.shift();
            Schichtplan.pop();
            Schichtplan.pop();
            sheetJP.getRange(datumsZeile + 1, mitarbeiterspalte, Schichtplan.length, Schichtplan[0].length).setValues(Schichtplan);

          } else if (!startDatumGefunden) { // error if date not found
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
              "⚠️ Datum nicht gefunden",
              "Das Startdatum: " + startDatumLesbar + " wurde im Jahresplan nicht gefunden!",
              SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
          }
        } else { // error: multiple employees found
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
            "⚠️ Namen mehrmals gefunden",
            "Der Name: " + mitarbeiter + " wurde im Jahresplan mehr als 1x gefunden!",
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (!mitarbeiterGefunden) { // error: employee not found
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
        "⚠️ Namen nicht gefunden",
        "Der Name: " + mitarbeiter + " wurde im Jahresplan nicht gefunden!",
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Es wurden " + counter + " Einträge bei " + mitarbeiter + "  eingetragen"); // SUMMARY
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Es wurden keine Eintragungen durchgeführt"); // didn't do anything
  }
}
```

So far I found out:

- I have to use `Excel.run` and `context.sync()` to read and insert from spreadsheets. But I haven't figured out exactly how to use it yet.
- I'll better use `let` and `const` instead of `var` to assign variables
- Maybe I can insert the entries easier with `context.sync()` instead of using this huge array.
- only Office-JS (I'll switch to an HTML-based page for starting the script instead of using a sheet (with button).)
- only Office-JS (I think it's better to use `async function()` with `await`)

Comment: Based on your code snippet I would use Office Scripts if you have access to them. You can read more about Office Scrips here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Comment: Thank you! But so far I haven't access to Office Scripts. Only Script Lab. But I thought the coding is the same?

Comment: The coding is similar, but the APIs are different. ScriptLab is just an add-in to test the Excel JavaScript APIs. It's not intended to do development. As a few examples, it doesn't support savings scripts and there's limited debugging support. Add-ins that use JavaScript APIs are intended to be created using Office Add-ins. Office Scripts are a derivative API based on the Excel JavaScript API. They abstract away a lot of things to make it easier to use. They also have other benefits. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/add-ins-differences

Comment: Fwiw, Script Lab can save scripts as Github gists.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a tool or guide that can help you move from Google Apps Script to Office Script or Office JS. I suggest posting questions with specific code snippets here at Stack Overflow, including what you have already tried in Office Scripts, and then I am sure there will be people in community that are interested in helping you make the transition.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I inserted a code snippet and some Ideas in my Question!

Comment: Wunderbar!  I think it would be useful, if you can also post a link to a sample workbook. Pls note that programming in Office Scripts is different from Office JS (Script Lab) since Office Scripts doesn’t use the asynchronious programming model. Your observations above applies to Office JS, but not to Office Scripts.

Comment: Plus, if you sign into Excel Web with a Microsoft 365 work or school account you should have an Automate tab in the ribbon and you can start coding with Office Scripts.

Comment: Sehr schön! :-) Thank you again, that helped me a lot! Unfortunately, we have only "Business Basic" without desktop apps. And that means no access to Office Scripts. But with your information, I think we should do an upgrade...